# Animate :hover css rule

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to animate the transition to a CSS :hover rule? I don't mean to animate into something that I specify in a script, but to something that is specified in CSS.

Comment: "I don't mean to animate into something that I specify in a script" Then why tag this [jquery]?

Comment: [CSS transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/) -- read all about 'em.

Comment: @BoltClock because I thought it is the right tool for the job. You might be misunderstanding my question though. I'm aware of CSS transitions, but they are yet to be widely supported.

Comment: Use Modernizr for support like I said below

Comment: If you want wider support than CSS transitions, [use jQuery `.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) -- however, it's impossible to get jQuery to recognize the styles you've put in a `:hover` pseudo-class. You'll have to code the changing styles separately in your JavaScript.

Comment: @Blazemonger that's exactly what I want, sad to hear it's not possible. Care to expand this comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSS transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/) are widely supported in modern browsers.

If you want wider support than CSS transitions, [use jQuery `.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

However, it's impossible to get jQuery to recognize the styles you've put in a `:hover` pseudo-class. You'll just have to code the changing styles separately in your JavaScript. (You could use some jQuery/JS trickery to extract the styles if they were added to a proper class, but not a pseudo-class.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and faster also CSS3 takes advantage of hardware acceleration which make them buttery smooth. I would recommend using Modernizr to check if the browser supports CSS3 transitions and then provide jQuery fallback support using animate.

CSS3 transitions work like this
http://jsfiddle.net/zzKYC/

EDIT: Here is also a perfect example of CSS3 transitions with Modernizr fallback support using jQuery's animate method

http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/animating.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to transition, but, here's a jsfiddle that does an ease in transition on color. I covered a few browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/NTjQG/